# Send to foreign mobile number with a local shortcode in MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Our client needs to send SMS to local phone number, but also foreign phone number.
With a local shortcode (France), is it possible to send SMS to foreign phone number also ?
Is there any restrictions ? or things to keep in mind regarding this issue ?

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the contract with Salesforce regarding the shortcode / longcode that is purchased for MobileConnect.

It is possible to have a the *longcode* activated for multiple countries, but with shortcodes there are probably more limitations. You'll need to contact your AE for more specifics.

Aside from that, the important thing is to understand the [**SuperMessage multiplier**](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/product-specific-terms/marketing-cloud-super-message-bundles.pdf) - as this is going to be different by country.